# Commit to Github from mongodb realm UI

Tags: mongodb, github, realm

I have a mongodb realm app that is synced to a github repo, so when I push something to the github repo, it's automatically deployed to mongo. So far so good. However, if someone makes a change to the app directly in the mongodb UI, those changes will not end up in the github repo.

I want the sync to be in both directions, so if a change is made in the mongodb UI a new commit should be created in the github repo.

Is there any way to set this up? Thanks.

---

Edit: At this point, the mongodb team has added this feature themselves, so it should work out of the box.

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question, did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @Bassem Unfortunately not. If you ever find a solution, please let me know :)